# How to conditionally run collection of stages in mongoose aggregate pipeline?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a used mongoose aggregate pipeline with many stages in one of my api endpoints. In that pipeline there is a `$unwind` stage and multiple `$lookup` stages that must only run if `images` array in document in not empty. How can I setup the pipeline such that a select few stages may or may not run based on a condition derived from a field within the documents?
Thank you for reading.

For reference, here is a sample document.

```
{
 _id: "6151387333f8e9001ff92429",
 title: "Boost Your Car With These Tips",
 description: "Follows these steps to get the most out of your car",
 images: [
  { 
   image: "5ebac534954b54139806c112", 
   caption: "Riding Ferreri", 
   credit: "5ebac534954b54139806c112" 
  },
  { 
   image: "4ebac534954b54139806c142", 
   caption: "Motor Garage", 
   credit: "6ebac534954b54139806c11e" 
  },
 ]
}
```

Comment: Multiple $lookup stages is an indication for a poor data design. Anyway, do you have some sample data?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have added a simple document in the original question.

Comment: How do you use even multiple `$lookup` with only one collection?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit there are multiple collections. There is only one collection that we are concerned with for this problem. The above example is a dummy document of that collection.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit you can see the images array in the above example. I had to use $unwind stage on that "images" field, and then run other stages in each of the resulting documents the comes from $unwind stage. But in some documents the images array is empty. So if I used the unwind stage on those documents, they will not appear in the final result. So I have to conditionally check if the images array is not empty and only then run other stages including the $unwind stage.

Comment: Did you try $unwind with `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true`?